# inserting elements of a table into an array

Tags: php, arrays, dom

Im trying to get some info of an external webpage into arrays.

here is the code to read the page:

```
 $url = 'http://dsrd.uc.cl/dara/libcursos/periodo21/ptj/ptj_5_data.html';
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get the source code
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

and here is the code to get the columns into an array

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(0);
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");

for ($i = 0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    $curso[$i] = $rows->item($i);

    /* Find columns and add it to your array */
}
print_r($curso);
```

however im only getting the arrays filled with "DOMElement Object ( )"

any sugestions? thx

**UPDATE**

forgot to add ->nodeValue;.... just stupid

thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `DOMElement`'s in it, so of course that is what you get. Depending on what you want, you could also store the `$rows->item($i)->value`, `$rows->item($i)->tagName`,`$rows->item($i)->textContent`, or `$rows->item($i)->ownerDocument->saveXML($rows->item($i))`.

What data do you *want* there?